# Loop through multi-dimensional array and remove certain keys

Tags: php, arrays, menu, nested, recursion

I've got a nested tree structure which is based on the array below:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => Startpage
            [uri] => 125
            [basename] => index.php
            [child] => 
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => Events
            [uri] => 0
            [basename] => 
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [24] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24
                            [parent] => 23
                            [name] => Public news
                            [uri] => 0
                            [basename] => 
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [27] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 27
                                            [parent] => 24
                                            [name] => Add
                                            [uri] => 100
                                            [basename] => news.public.add.php
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                    [28] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 28
                                            [parent] => 24
                                            [name] => Overview
                                            [uri] => 101
                                            [basename] => news.public.overview.php
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [25] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 25
                            [parent] => 23
                            [name] => Private news
                            [uri] => 0
                            [basename] => 
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [29] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 29
                                            [parent] => 25
                                            [name] => Add
                                            [uri] => 67
                                            [basename] => news.private.add.php
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                    [30] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 30
                                            [parent] => 25
                                            [name] => Overview
                                            [uri] => 68
                                            [basename] => news.private.overview.php
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [26] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 26
                            [parent] => 23
                            [name] => Calendar
                            [uri] => 0
                            [basename] => 
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [31] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 31
                                            [parent] => 26
                                            [name] => Add
                                            [uri] => 69
                                            [basename] => news.event.add.php
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                    [32] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 32
                                            [parent] => 26
                                            [name] => Overview
                                            [uri] => 70
                                            [basename] => news.event.overview.php
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

I'm looking for a function to loop (recursive?) through the array and remove some keys.

I my system I can allow users to certain functions/pages and if I deny access to the whole "block" "Events", the array will look like this:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'parent' => '0',
    'name' => 'Start page',
    'uri' => '125',
    'basename' => 'index.php',
    'child' => '',
  ),
  23 => 
  array (
    'id' => '23',
    'parent' => '0',
    'name' => 'Events',
    'uri' => '0',
    'basename' => NULL,
    'child' => 
    array (
      24 => 
      array (
        'id' => '24',
        'parent' => '23',
        'name' => 'Public news',
        'uri' => '0',
        'basename' => NULL,
        'child' => '',
      ),
      25 => 
      array (
        'id' => '25',
        'parent' => '23',
        'name' => 'Private news',
        'uri' => '0',
        'basename' => NULL,
        'child' => '',
      ),
      26 => 
      array (
        'id' => '26',
        'parent' => '23',
        'name' => 'Calendar',
        'uri' => '0',
        'basename' => NULL,
        'child' => '',
      ),
    ),
  )
)
```

As you can see above, the whole "block" "Events" is useless right now, becuase there is no page associated with each option. So I need to find all "keys" where "basename" is null AND where child is not an array or where the array is empty and remove them.
I found this function when searching the site:

```
function searchAndDestroy(&$a, $key, $val){
    foreach($a as $k => &$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $r = searchAndDestroy($v, $key, $val);
            if($r) {
                unset($a[$k]);
            }
        } elseif ($key == $k && $val == $v) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It can be used to remove a key any where in the array, but only based in one thing, for example remove all keys where "parent" equals "23". But I need to find and remove (unset) all keys where "basename" is null AND where child isn't an array or where the array is empty.
Can anyone help me out and possibly tweak the function above?

Thank you,

Comment: And finally he stopped writing :-)

Comment: can you please provide the array structure with `var_export` instead of `print_r`

Comment: @Parth You need to oil your mouse wheel to go faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Added this function to my class:

```
private function cleanTree(&$arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => &$item) {
        if(!$item["child"] && empty($item["basename"])){
            unset($arr[$key]);
```

```
    }elseif(is_array($item["child"])){
        if(count($item["child"]) == 0){
            unset($arr[$item["id"]]);
        }else{
            $this->cleanTree($item["child"]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

To remove unnecessary elements on the ROOT level(s) as well as anyone else, just run the above twice.

Comment: What if useless items go down 3 levels?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting the test for which elements to destroy in the search function, pass a function to test for targets.

```
function searchAndDestroy(&$a, $targetp){
    foreach($a as $k => &$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            searchAndDestroy($v, $targetp);
        } 
        if ($targetp($k, $v)) {
            unset($a[$k]);
        }
    }
}

searchAndDestroy($menu, function ($k, $v) {
        return is_array($v) 
            && array_key_exists('basename', $v) && empty($v['basename'])
            && (empty($v['child']) || count($v['child']) == 0);
    });
```

For PHP < 5.3 (or if you call `searchAndDestroy` with that function in more than one spot), name the function and pass the name rather than an anonymous function.